# I need my random values to look like they are rolling C#

Tags: c#, random, label

I have five dice labels and I have a method `Roll()` that sets their
text value. At the moment when the roll method happens it just makes the numbers appear, but I would like them to look like they are rolling.

Here is what I have

```
//Roll() simulates the rolling of this die. 
    public void Roll()
    {
        if (Active) {

            faceValue = random.Next(1, 7);

            label.Text = faceValue.ToString();
        }

    }
```

`Roll()` is called from another class like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++){
            dice[i].Roll();
        }
```

**My Question is:**

How can I let it looks like they are rolling through a set of numbers then stop on a number ?

Comment: Assuming Winforms: You will need a Timer for this kind of animation.

Comment: How is `Roll` called?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++){
                dice[i].Roll();
            }

Comment: @TheLethalCoder for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++){
                dice[i].Roll();
            }

Comment: Call it several times with a timer between each one, maybe starts at 100 ms and increase till 500 ms. Then, call it for the last time and set that value as the final value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public async void Roll()
    {
        if (Active)
        {
           for (int i=0;i<20;i++) //Number of rolls before showing final
           {
               await Task.Delay(100);
               label.Text = random.Next(1, 7).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't show the "slowing roll" spirit. Maybe start with 100 and increment by 50 on each pass.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an exception when I call it in the other class

Comment: @FirstStep i get a 'System.TypeInitializationException'

Comment: It's part of class Form. If you use from other class you must check that label.Text can be changed. And random is accessible...

Answer (score 0):

I tested a Little and this Looks good done in WPF with a [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Tick += Roll;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(1);

        Random r = new Random();
        timer.Start();
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    public void Roll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        increment++;
        if (increment >= 250)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            increment = 0;
        }
        DiceLabel.Content = r.Next(1, 7).ToString();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(increment*3000);
    }
```

If you want it faster or longer you can play with the value from:

```
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(increment*3000);
```

here to set the time between the new number is shown.

And for the time to Dice is rolling, you can play with:

```
if (increment >= 250)
```

Hope that helps, have fun.